# Want to do more at work, how to approach it?

Tags: professionalism, management, career-development, colleagues, task-management

I am 25 and I have freshly started to work in a risk management department of a bank in December 2014. In the beginning it was very stressful, because I worked in an IT project(I studied computer science in colleague). I am quite keen on the IT side and therefore they heavily used me in the beginning, because my strength is there.

However, I want to get much deeper in the daily work also my colleagues do, risk analysis. My colleagues “daily work” is definitely different from day to day, because our analysis depends on economic developments.

The thing that bothers me the most is, that I do not have much do to(since the last two weeks!!!). I would like to contribute much more to the team, than I do now. At the moment, I am just supporting one of the senior colleagues sometimes and my second task is to help business wise in the IT project, if there is something difficult to do. That is not much work atm.

I am constantly asking the senior colleague if there is something I could help him with, but he is always on the move and I think he does not want to bother with a junior, whom he has to explain some things in the beginning.

Furthermore, I am the only junior atm in my department and so I think the other colleagues do not care much about me and what I do.

I really want to get more into the field of risk management! I love to work hard and have shown in my department (during the heights of the IT project) that this is not a big issue for me. At my age “working means learning a lot” for me. The best thing would be if I could have a small piece in a risk management project.

What should I do? How should I approach my boss about that?(I do not want that he thinks that I am not independent) Should I talk to my boss about that?

I appreciate your answer!

Comment: see also: [How to find work to do when starting a new job](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/23532/how-to-find-work-to-do-when-starting-a-new-job)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How should I approach my boss about that?(I do not want that he thinks
>   that I am not independent)

Try scheduling a meeting with your boss. Drop him an email asking for a short meeting to talk about your progress to date. See how things are going, where things are heading.

> I really want to get more into the field of risk management! I love to work hard and have shown in my department (during the heights of the IT project) that this is not a big issue for me. At my age “working means learning a lot” for me. The best thing would be if I could have a small piece in a risk management project.

Tell this to your boss! Superiors love to hear enthusiasm and passion from their employees.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to tell your boss that you want to move into risk management. You could tell him that you'd like to help with some risk management tasks/projects while you are not busy with IT.

Comment: I don't know about his boss, but I would ask why if someone volunteered to work on other tasks. I suggest having an answer ready.

Comment: @JeffO My own ready answer, if I were in the OP's position,  would be that I'd like to take advantage of the fact that I am already onsite to also learn a bit about the business and hopefully, it helps me do a better job  for the users. IT doesn't operate in a vacuum.